# $state and $stateParams are undefined when go to child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I face with such problem:
I have the following state hierarchy: bookings(abstract)->services->new->promo

```
        $stateProvider.state("bookings", {
        url: "/bookings",
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            "@": {
                templateUrl: "/Static/routing-template.html"
            },
            "content@bookings": {
                templateUrl: "/Static/scheduler/scheduler.html"
            }
        }
    });
        $stateProvider.state("bookings.services", {
        url: "/services",
        views: {
            "menu@bookings": {
                templateUrl: "/Static/services/services-list.html",
                controller: "ServicesController"
            },
            "content@bookings": {
                templateUrl: "/Static/scheduler/scheduler.html"
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            currencies: function(currencyDataService) {
                return currencyDataService.loadData();
            },
            currentCurrency: function(currencyDataService) {
                return currencyDataService.loadCurrent();
            },
            servicesDataService: function($servicesDataService) {
                return $servicesDataService.loadData();
            }

        }
    });
        $stateProvider.state("bookings.services.new", {
        url: "/new/",
        views: {
            "content@bookings": {
                templateUrl: "/Static/services/add-edit-service.html",
                controller: "ServiceAddEditController as controller"
            }
        },
        params: {
            serviceId: 0,
            //to restore state when back from promo setup tab, null when normally add new service 
            serviceModel: null
        }

    });
    $stateProvider.state('bookings.services.new.promo', {
        url: "promo",
        views: {
            "content@bookings": {
                templateUrl: "/Static/services/promo-tab.html",
                controller: "PromoSetupController as promo"
            }
        },
        params: {
            serviceModel: {}
        }
    });
```

For three first steps it works fine. But when I try to go to a `promo` state, controller initializing but $stateParams and $state is `undefined`. PromoControllerCode:

```
angular.module("CommandCenterApp")
.controller("PromoSetupController", [
    function($state, $stateParams) {
        var self = this;
        self.model = $stateParams.serviceModel;
        console.log("Model:", self.model);
    }
]);
```

And how I go to this state:

```
 <p ui-sref="bookings.services.new.promo({serviceModel:controller.typeModel})" class="fake-link hidden-sm hidden-xs">Set up promo codes</p>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why you declared `serviceModel` in parent in child route..better keep it in  child state..

Comment: should the `url` for `promo` also start with a forward slash (`/`) - like `url: "/promo",`?

Comment: @PankajParkar it needs for save changes done in state `bookings.services.new` when you go to promo tab and backs again to restore changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the controller syntax. either take away the brackets:

```
angular.module("CommandCenterApp")
  .controller("PromoSetupController", 
    function($state, $stateParams) {
      var self = this;
      self.model = $stateParams.serviceModel;
      console.log("Model:", self.model);
  }
);
```

or add the correct bracket syntax:

```
angular.module("CommandCenterApp")
  .controller("PromoSetupController", ['$state', '$stateParams',
    function($state, $stateParams) {
      var self = this;
      self.model = $stateParams.serviceModel;
      console.log("Model:", self.model);
    }
]);
```